# Why data.frame doesn't parse the data frames arguments?

Tags: r

It seems to be contrary to what is written in the help file:

> "If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to data.frame it is as if
>   each component or column had been passed as a separate argument"

So what do I do wrong ?

Example code:

```
d <- c("bla", "bla", "blou", "blou", "bli")
dtest <- data.frame(d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dtest2 <- data.frame(dtest, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
dtest3 <- data.frame(dtest[[1]], stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

str(c(dtest2, dtest3))
```

One is a character vector, the other has been converted to a factor (following the stringsAsFactor=TRUE behavior). They "should" be both factors.

I actually want to use data.frame(df) to convert an existing data frame with some character columns into a data frames with the corresponding factors.

Comment: I know that I could do the latter with something like:
`i <- sapply(df,is.character)
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.factor)` But the question of parsing the data frames is still raised!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this: `dtest <- data.frame(d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` does not set an attribute that prevents subsequent calls to data.frame from applying the default stringsAsFactors-behavior. You could achieve such a state of affairs by setting:

```
  options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If on the other hand you were hoping for similar behavior, you should send the entire column to data.frame:

```
> dtest2 <- data.frame(dtest)
> dtest3 <- data.frame(dtest[1])
> 
> str(c(dtest2, dtest3))
List of 2
 $ d: chr [1:5] "bla" "bla" "blou" "blou" ...
 $ d: chr [1:5] "bla" "bla" "blou" "blou" ...
```

If you want to get all the columns of a dataframe re-evaluated then I suppose you could do this:

```
data.frame(lapply(dtest, as.vector) )

> str(data.frame(lapply(dtest, as.vector) ))
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ d: Factor w/ 3 levels "bla","bli","blou": 1 1 3 3 2
```

Comment: I think you did not understood my question (my bad). I precisely want the subsequent calls from data.frame to reformat the data frame in the same way it would if I fed it with the actual column vectors as separate elements. To say it differently, I don't understand why in your example, dtest2 and dtest3 **are not** factors.

Comment: Data.frames are lists of lists. List are able to hold attributes. Applying data.frame to an existing dataframes should not change the attributes of the lists (although apparently you feel differently). You have already identified how to get a factor (using "[[") so is there a problem?

Comment: Yes. I want the function data.frame to behave as it should, or understand what I don't. I slightly modified the example to reflect more the "problem" I see.

Comment: I amended my answer to cover that possibility, but adding the stringsAsFactors argument does nothing differently, since that is the default.

Comment: I know it doesn't change anything (provided that the default option is the factory one) but I wanted to highlight the asymmetry of the behavior between the two instances of data.frame(). You answered my question by giving a standard method to do what data.frame should do with data frames. Why does the help file seem to be wrong then?

Comment: The help file refers to the "components" of a dataframe which I take to be the columns which are sub-lists. They are what you would get with `dfrm[ , 1, drop=FALSE]` rather than what you get with `dfrm[[1]]` or `dfrm$d`.